# Appending an element with an ID that matches a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a couple of other questions that were similar but I'm still not getting the needed result.

So I have a list:

```
<ul>
  <li class="class1"></li>
  <li class="class2"></li>
  <li class="class3"></li>
  <li class="class4"></li>
  <li class="class5"></li>
</ul>
```

And then I have a set of dynamically-generated spans with IDs that match those classes.

```
<span id="class1"></span>
<span id="class2"></span>
<span id="class3"></span>
<span id="class4"></span>
<span id="class5"></span>
```

I need to append each of those spans to their matched list item. So `.class1` to `#class1`. I figured there would be something easy like:

`$(this).find('#' + this.className).appendTo(this);`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Replace `$(this).find` with `$`. Learn about what `find` does: https://api.jquery.com/find/ .

Comment: Why are you doing a *find()*? If its an ID, you can just do: `$('#' + this.className).appendTo(this);`. Its a bit hard to know for sure if thats any good for you, as your line is out of context (i.e we can't see where its being triggered from)

Comment: Great question. I think because it's Monday and I had forgotten what `.find()` even did in the first place.

Comment: So when using `$('#' + this.className).appendTo(this)` I get the following console error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined` Thoughts?

Comment: _"have a set of dynamically-generated spans with IDs that match those classes"_ How are `span` elements dynamically generated ? , can include `js` at Question where `span` elements are created ? Should `span` elements be appended to `li` immediately when created ?

Comment: @AlexMarple - please provide us with a bit more of an example of your code. It's hard to make a suggestion with just 1 line of code ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("li[class^='class']").on("click", function(){
    $("#"+ this.className).appendTo(this);
});
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/musisa/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

NOTE: your code will break as soon you add another class to your element:

```
<li class="class2 something"></li>
```

cause than you'll be erroneously searching for an ID element called `#class2 something`.

You'd better go using `data-*` attributes instead of class names.

```js
$("[data-get]").on("click", function(){
  $("#class"+ this.dataset.get).appendTo(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-get="1" class="class">1</li>
  <li data-get="2" class="class">2</li>
  <li data-get="3" class="class">3</li>
  <li data-get="4" class="class">4</li>
  <li data-get="5" class="class">5</li>
</ul>

<span id="class1">s1</span>
<span id="class2">s2</span>
<span id="class3">s3</span>
<span id="class4">s4</span>
<span id="class5">s5</span>
```

Comment: @RokoCBuljan `span` elements do not appear to already be in document ?

Comment: @guest271314 so what. The clickable LI elements on whom the event is bound to are static elements.

Comment: Yes, though if `span` is not already in `DOM` would return `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined` , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741582/appending-an-element-with-an-id-that-matches-a-class#comment55251595_33741582

Comment: Your solution should return expected result - if elements already in document .OP has not shown where `span` elements were actually appended to `DOM` at `js` at Question

Comment: @guest271314 than I'd close this discussion till OP collects his thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, if I understood correctly:

```html
$(function() {     
        $("span[id^='class']").each(function() {
                var liObj = $("li[class='" + this.id + "']");
                if (liObj.length == 1) {
                    $(this).appendTo(liObj);
                }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not posting all of my code. It didn't seem necessary. The answer is:

```
$( '#' + this.className ).appendTo('.' + this.className);
```

I knew it was something stupidly simple. Thanks for everyone who responded!